# A trigonometry exercise involving the law of sines and cosines.

Tags: trigonometry

While studying mathematics, I came across this exercise, which I can't seem to find a way of resolving:

> Regarding the following figure, express, as a function of $x$, the perimetre of the trapezoid and the area of the Triangle [ADC]. Calculate the value, approximated to a tenth of a degree, of the angle CÂB.

[image: Here is the figure. (I can't embed the image and the quality isn't good at all, I am sorry.)]

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: where is $x$ situated?

Comment: You don't have enough information.

Comment: I've added it, I forgot about it before (sorry!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the angle $ACD = \theta$. Let length $EC = l$. Now compute $\tan(\theta)$ from triangle $ACD$:

$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{6x+l}\tag{1}$$

Now look at $\triangle BEC$. Compute $\tan(\angle{BCE}) = \tan(30^\circ + \theta)$:

$$\begin{align}
\tan{30^\circ + \theta} = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+ \tan \theta}{1-\frac{\tan(\theta)}{\sqrt{3}}} &=\frac{x}{l}\\
\frac{1+\sqrt{3} \tan(\theta)}{\sqrt{3}-\tan(\theta)}&=\frac{x}{l}\tag{2}
\end{align} $$

Now you have two equations with two variables ($\tan\theta,l$). Simply solve and get $l$.

You can easily calculate other required parameters. I leave that up to you!

Comment: Just to clarify, in the first (and second equation), $l = EC$, right? Thanks, by the way!

Comment: @Rodrigo Oops its a typo. Correct!